# Waiting for data by serial port during certain time in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, serial-port, pyserial

I have to wait a certain size data by serial port during certain time. If I get less data for this time, then I would like to avoid read data. If I get enough data early, then I would like to read them and stop waiting data too.

My current solution looks like this:

```
serial.open()
start_time = time()
while serial.in_waiting < expected_data_size: # waiting certain size of data
    if time_to_wait < time() - start_time: # time is expired
        serial.close()
        return
data = serial.read(expected_data_size)
serial.close()
```

But I think it's not good solution, because comparisons (in "while" and "if" blocks) occur a lot of times, while it waits for a data.

Please, advise me, how to implement it better in Python 3. To work with serial port I use [pySerial](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyserial).

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you don't need to invent new wheel. 
1) when you open the port, you should setup timeout.
2) after port is open, you should setup data size to be read in "read" API.

read API will return either with the size of data or return less data if time out occurs.

see sample from documentation:

```
>>> with serial.Serial('/dev/ttyS1', 19200, timeout=1) as ser:
...     x = ser.read()          # read one byte
...     s = ser.read(10)        # read up to ten bytes (timeout)
```

Comment: Many thanks for your answer! This is exactly what I need! Could you tell me one more? I know that the first N seconds I won't receive enough data in any case. Is it worth to add sleep(N) before ser.read(data_size) or not?

Comment: @RomanAlexeev , you don't need to add sleep, API will handle that for you.

Comment: Thank you for your help!